# How to rearrange multiple columns (with dplyr) for faceted bar graphs (generated with ggplot) in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a data frame similar to the one below.

(In my original data frame, I have ps and qs + their confidence intervals in addition to gs and us).

```
df <- read.table(text="
       university      gs  gs.ci.l  gs.ci.u       us  us.ci.l  us.ci.u
1           A        0.90     0.89     0.92     0.08    0.079    0.081
2           B        0.80     0.78     0.82     0.18    0.179    0.181
3           C        0.70     0.69     0.71     0.27    0.269    0.271
4           D        0.60     0.64     0.63     0.30    0.291    0.34", header=T)
```

[Q1]
I would like to rearrange my data frame with dplyr to create faceted bar graphs (one facet per university, each facet displaying 2 bars (gs + confidence intervals[gs.ci.l; gs.ci.u] and us + confidence intervals[us.ci.l; us.ci.u])

What would be the best way to rearrange the data frame in order to generate the aforementioned output? 
I tried to use gather ( ) to force the means and the confidence limits into the same columns, respectively.

[Q2]
Relatedly, is there an elegant way to arrange outputs from dplyr::summarise( ) %>% select( ) immediately in columns? In my example, I would have wanted to arrange "gs" and "us" in a column named "mean", "gs.ci.l" and "us.ci.l" in the column "ci_low" and "gs.ci.u" and "gs.ci.u" in a column called "ci_up" in advance.

Comment: Better to visually show the expected output. Makes it faster to follow(in my opinion).

Comment: It would look a bit like this: https://strengejacke.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/groupbars-5.png. Each colour would represent a university, but there would be only two bars per colour (gs, us) with CI for each single bar displayed. I hope this helps.

Comment: I would suggest using `tidyr::gather` to convert into long format, and then use `mutate` to create a variable telling if each column is related to gs or us, and another telling if the column is the base value or the ci.l or ci.u value. Then you can feed those straight into ggplot.

Comment: @Jon Spring. So how would you do that in practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regrades to Q1 - I am not sure I am envisioning your intended output correctly. Is below in the ball park? NOTE: I am only doing minimal formatting here. Also, the example has some confused and slight CIs, which makes part of the output not make sense or hard to read. Formatting will help in some cases.

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- df %>% 
  select(university, mu = gs, ci.l = gs.ci.l,ci.u = gs.ci.u) %>% 
  mutate(label = 'gs') %>% 
  bind_rows(., df %>% 
          select(university, mu = us, ci.l = us.ci.l,ci.u = us.ci.u) %>% 
          mutate(label = 'us'))

test %>% ggplot(., aes(y = mu, x = label)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ci.l, ymax=ci.u, width =.3)) +
  facet_wrap(~university) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you! Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution as @Peter_Evan, using `tidyr::gather` and `tidyr::spread` to prepare the data:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(col, val, gs:us.ci.u) %>% 
  mutate(categ = str_sub(col, end = 2), stat = str_sub(col, start = 4)) %>%
  mutate(stat = if_else(stat == "", "mean", stat)) %>%
  select(-col) %>% 
  spread(stat, val) %>%

  ggplot(aes(categ)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = mean)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ci.l, ymax = ci.u)) +
  facet_wrap(~university, nrow = 1)
```

[image]